VBA code not deleting entire row causing data to be misaligned
I'm working on an Excel macro to delete rows from a table when either of two columns contain #N/A. The table is named TrialData and is on the worksheet Trial Sheet. The code should delete the entire row if either the Dog or Partner Dog columns contain #N/A. However, the code only seems to delete columns A-C and not the entire row. Can anyone help me figure out why this is happening?
This is the current code:
Sub DeleteRowsBasedOnNA()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim delRng As Range

' Set worksheet and table
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trial Sheet")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("TrialData") ' Ensure the table is named 'TrialData'

' Activate worksheet (optional)
ws.Activate

' Clear any existing filters
If tbl.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

' Loop through each row in the table to find #N/A in columns 2 (Dog) and 3 (Partner Dog)
For Each cell In tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange
    If IsError(cell.Value) Or IsError(cell.Offset(0, 1).Value) Then
        If delRng Is Nothing Then
            Set delRng = cell.EntireRow
        Else
            Set delRng = Union(delRng, cell.EntireRow)
        End If
    End If
Next cell

' Delete the identified rows
If Not delRng Is Nothing Then
    delRng.Delete
End If

' Clear filters and reset AutoFilter mode
If tbl.AutoFilter.FilterMode Then
    tbl.AutoFilter.ShowAllData
End If

End Sub


What about a single code line to solve the problem? tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).EntireRow.Delete. You only need to handle the error raised in case of no error existing in the two table columns...

Please, try the next simpler code variant, not involving any iteration:
Sub deleteTableErrorRows()
 Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Trial Sheet")
 Dim tbl As ListObject: Set tbl = sh.ListObjects("TrialData")
 
 Dim rngDel As Range
 On Error Resume Next
  Set rngDel = tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors)
 On Error GoTo 0
 If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Your code as it is should work, I think. Even if, it is more efficient to not keep all rows in the Union range. You can try placing only the found cell in the range and delete at the end as above rngDel.EntireRow.Delete.
If (for unknown reason) your installation is not able to delete a range of erroring cells (very strange, anyhow) you can replace those cells content with something as: tbl.ListColumns(2).DataBodyRange.Resize(, 2).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, xlErrors).value = "ZZZZ", then search for "ZZZZ"...
